# Sagemath: How to change the type of a float number to Real Literal

Tags: sage

I am working with floats in SageMath and I would like to change the type of a float number from `sage.rings.real_double.RealDoubleElement` to `sage.rings.real_mpfr.RealLiteral`. I can switch the other way around.

```
print(type(0.1))
#output: <class 'sage.rings.real_mpfr.RealLiteral'>

print(type(RDF(0.1)))
#output: <class 'sage.rings.real_double.RealDoubleElement'>
```

I have tried a few methods but I could not find a way, and I was not able to find a way by looking at the documentations. Using `RR(RDF(0.1))` does not quite work either as its type is `<class 'sage.rings.real_mpfr.RealNumber'>`.

Is it possible to change a float to `sage.rings.real_mpfr.RealLiteral` in SageMath?